Как обновить ячейку в postgreSQL через sequileze?
Как можно обновить ячейку в sequilize. Снизу я пробовал через метод пост, по id находит, где изменять статус
async statusConfirmation(req, res, next){
        try {
            const {id, status} = req.body
            const clientOrderRouter = await clientOrder.create({status: status}, {where: {id: id}})
            return res.json(clientOrderRouter)
        } catch (err){
          next(ApiError.badRequest(err.message))
        }
    }

Роутер
router.post('/api/createClientOrderPut', clientOrderController.statusConfirmation)

это запрос на стороне клиета
export const statusConfirmation = async (id) => {
    const {data} = await $authHost.post('api/createClientOrderPut', {id, status: "Подтверждено"})
    return data
}

Кнопка для изменения статуса
    function handleUpdateClick(id){
        statusConfirmation(id).then(
            window.location.reload()

        ).catch(error => alert(error.response.data.message))
    }


clientOrder.update?

@nörbörnën router.update нет такого

я же написал clientOrder.update, моделька или репозиторий, не знаю терминологии sequelize.
